# why my navigation item / bar disappear from my storyboard in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have some issue in the storyboard in my navigation bar/item. the navigation bar/item appear if I run the app. but in my storyboard it seems disappear, as we can see in the document outline, the navigation bar/item is actually available, but I don't know why it doesn't show up in my storyboard. it makes me worried.

I have tried to quit the Xcode and simulator but it still disappear in my storyboard. here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Remove the navigation bar and add it again

Comment: What's your setting for Simulated Metrics > Top bar for the viewcontroller in Interface builder? Make sure it's set to "Inferred" and not "None"

Comment: If it is set to none, then it won't be visible in NavigationVC rite? @andlin

Comment: It will still be visible in the Navigation Controller in IB if you set it to None. Unless you set it to None for the navigation controller as well.

Comment: If the navigation bar appears correctly when you run the app, it's ok ryt ?

Comment: ya then y r u worrying about storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the desired view controller and then select the attribute inspector -from the utilities section- and check what is the selected value for "Top Bar":

[image]

In your case, I assume that you would find it as "None", change it to "Inferred" and it should be as excepted.

Answer (score 1):

**The navigation bar on storyboard** is set to `inferred` by default. Which means it appears/disappears depending on the view controller you were selecting before it on storyboard.

> To see the navigation bar for a view controller select its parent
>   navigation controller first.

***They are trying to mimic the iOS behavior on this. When you push the view controller into a navigation controller the navigation bar appears. Same thing in the storyboard when you select a navigation controller the bar appears.***